# Wordpress Custom Loop doesn't show any posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to add a custom loop to display post titles from the category homepage. Here's the code I have so far so, but it's not displaying any posts. BTW, I'm using this code in single.php.

```
<?php $recentPosts = new WP_Query(); ?>
<?php if ( $recentPosts->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php $recentPosts->query_posts( array ( 'category_name' => 'homepage', 'posts_per_page' => 10 ) ); ?>
           <?php while ($recentPosts->have_posts()) : $recentPosts->the_post(); ?>
<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

I'm not too sure what's going on, but would appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing a lot of unnecessary messing around with your query object. Since you're dealing with an archive page, you should be able to create a new template file called **category-homepage.php** (assuming the slug of the category is `homepage`). In it, you could place something like the following:

```
$args = array(
    'category_name' => 'homepage', 
    'posts_per_page' => 10
);
$recentPosts = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $recentPosts->have_posts() ) : 
    while ( $recentPosts->have_posts() ) : $recentPosts->the_post(); ?>

    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Again, since it's a category archive page, you shouldn't be doing anything to *single.php*. You can read more about template hierarchy [in the Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/).